# Can I use an air pump for a short amount of time to pump out some water out of a small container?

Tags: pump, air-filter

I am working on a small 3.5l (~1g) container as a [Paludarium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paludarium) (a type of vivarium that incorporates both terrestrial and aquatic elements). I want to put [this](https://www.amazon.de/Uniclife-Aquarium-Schwammfilter-Schaumfilter-Kit-Airline-Schlauch/dp/B09JFB417D?pd_rd_w=xNctP&content-id=amzn1.sym.995b3ade-87fd-4685-9950-c7995e7b483c&pf_rd_p=995b3ade-87fd-4685-9950-c7995e7b483c&pf_rd_r=G7DV50RYNG868GR5RTYK&pd_rd_wg=v5B11&pd_rd_r=b3ee1bf6-fe48-4aa9-bdeb-f4390340bd82&pd_rd_i=B09JFB417D&ref_=pd_bap_d_rp_1_t&th=1) nanofilter and attach an air pump on the outside. But I would also want to do water changes (in this case about half liters every 2 weeks or something) and I was wondering if I can use a product like [this](https://www.amazon.de/dp/B0822FFHD9/ref=sspa_dk_detail_5?ie=UTF8&psc=1&pd_rd_i=&pd_rd_i=B0822FFHD9p13NParams&smid=A17TZDKR0ADC1X&s=sports&sp_csd=d2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9kZXRhaWw) to do both.

Most of the time, it will pump air into the container and once every few weeks I will interchange the inlet and outlet so that I can suck out some water from the container.

What are my other alternatives? How can I achieve this task?

Answer (score 3):

Fashion a cover for the container with a tube that reaches the bottom of the container coming through it. If you can make it seal well enough, continuing to pump air in will pump water out the tube.

Most air pumps don't work well, or at all, when asked to pump water. But air pressure will easily move water. The more traditional approach is to siphon the water out.

For the scale of this, a turkey baster from the kitchen supplies would also work fine.